# Write binary data in QT '\n' 0x10->0x0d,0x010

Tags: c++, qt

I work on project that involved writing binary data, I use QString for storing line and then save it on hard by Qfile

```
 data.append(QChar(10));
```

and I set encoding to "ISO-8859-1", anyway when the data equal to 10 I as showed above, the saved data is 0x0d,0x0a I find the problem source ,10='\n' and Qt change it to '\n\r' so it happened.

How can I fix it?

Comment: How are you opening your file? How are you writing to it? Please show your code.

Comment: Why don't you just write `'\n'` when you mean that?

Comment: I only wanna save file not open it, and @Roland I have number only I check '\n' to it seem Qt change it to \r\n

Comment: Please show us how you open the file.

Comment: And tell us on which platform you are.

Comment: I use windows, I can't understand why you said "Open" I just want to save file ...

Comment: Open as in open a file/device before you can write to it? http://doc.trolltech.com/latest/qiodevice.html#open

Comment: By the way, if you're working with binary data you should be using QByteArray, not QString

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason, because the QFile object that I had created is in Text mode so when QFile want to write file it changes /n to /r/n the code below is the previous code that have problem in binary because of existence of `QIODevice::Text`

```
QFile myfile;
myfile.setFileName("build/Data.bin");
if(!myfile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly|QIODevice::Text))
    return;
```

for binary mode simply we can omite `QIODevice::Text` so the second line change to

```
if(!myfile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
```

at first I think this is the Qt's bug, and try to use ofstream to write file, the same thing happened with ofstream, and finally writing binary code with ofstream is showed below
the point is `std::ios_base::binary`

```
ofstream file;
file.open ("example.txt", std::ios_base::out | std::ios_base::binary);
file << (byte)10;
file.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question **and** answer are poor for several reasons. Here are the problems I've spotted immediately:

1. If you're *really* writing binary data, **do not use strings**. For reasons why, read and understand the following pages:
   [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/printerFriendly/articles/Unicode.html)
   [QString class documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#details)
   [QChar class documentation](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qchar.html)
2. The problem of getting "\r\n" stems from issue #1 but you would not find this problem on a Linux based operating system.
3. You haven't included what type the `data` object is in your question, which means we don't *really* know what `data.append(...)` is doing. Make sure your posts include a [short, self contained, correct (compilable), example](http://sscce.org/). Furthermore, in the answer you posted, there is no mention of this `data` object.
4. What is a `byte`? It's not part of C++ or Qt and those are the only two tags you've given us to go on.
5. In your answer you've flipped to using C++ streams instead. Be wary of doing this as you bypass a lot of the 'safety' features included by using Qt streams. If you're already using Qt, use it for as much as you can as it's designed to work together.